# What third-party options are there for working with strings in C?

Tags: c, string, libraries, arrays

I've been aware for awhile that I code about 17x faster in Python than in C, and I guess I sort of assumed I wasn't much of a programmer until I really thought about it and realized that the only problem is that I can't handle C strings/char arrays/char pointers/whatever. I have a block about them, and manipulating them takes me hours. I do not have this problem in C++.

But life forces me to code in pure C at the moment, and I'm trying to find if there's some third-party library I can add that will make my life easier. I did some googling and I didn't really find much. I'm starting to consider making it myself, but I feel like I'd be reinventing the wheel. Surely there's something out there? Does anyone know of something like that? Something that makes C a little more like C++ in that respect. I realize that's a silly idea, since that's the point of C++, but you understand, I'm sure.

Comment: @Aerovistae : You shouldn't tag questions for a language for which you do not want an answer – the `c++` tag is probably what threw @blearn off. :-]

Comment: @blearn I think he wants a C library, not C++.

Comment: Sorry, haha. I was half-hoping some C++ guru would descend from the heaven to inform me that they'd created an #include <C++> for C.

Comment: *"I can't handle C strings/char arrays/char pointers/whatever. I have a block about them, and manipulating them takes me hours"* - That tells me you have a block when it comes to pointers (i.e., manipulating memory directly) in general, which is a must for any serious C programmer.  This is about more than just strings.  Some people seem to have a (drastically) more difficult time with pointers than others.

Comment: It's not pointers in general, it's arrays of pointers/pointers to arrays. Especially ones that may or may not use null-termination. Especially when other coders use the extremely confusing (to me) mixed syntax of either `char[] variableName` or `char * variableName`. So you're not far off, no. I definitely have a bit of trouble there. I should probably open another question about the difference there, actually.

Comment: @Aerovistae That's something that's worth figuring out *first* - A C library will likely not help solve that issue, at least not entirely, as its such a core concept you must master to be effective in C.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718929/how-do-strings-and-char-arrays-work-in-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is the [Better String Library](http://bstring.sourceforge.net/), which is a pure C library for working with "strings" which tries to avoid many of the issues with standard C string handling.

Comment: But that's C++, is it not? How can I use it with C files?

Comment: @Aerovistae Nope.  It's plain C, with a C++ wrapper (included, but optional).

Comment: It's a shame - so many green checks in the matrix and no i18n support :(

Comment: @pst Yeah - but could still be useful depending on the need.

Answer (score 3):

http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.34/glib-utilities.html

http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.34/glib-Strings.html

It's the foundation of gnome, but you can use it independently from gnome, I think.
According to the overview page, "It works on many UNIX-like platforms, as well as Windows and OS X."

Answer (score 2):

You may begin resolving your pointer/array/string problem by reading the related questions on SO. There's no shortage of such questions.

There are a few important things that you must learn and understand in order to write correct C code containing pointers/arrays/strings:

1. Declarations of pointers, arrays, pointers to pointers, pointers to arrays, arrays of arrays, arrays of pointers and so on and so forth. C declarations are truly odd to the uninitiated. But, they are learnable and there are some tools like `cdecl` that can quickly translate abracadabrish declarations into plain English or the other way around.
2. If you see that a function declares one of its parameters as an array (e.g. `void f(int a[])`), don't believe your eyes. It's a pointer, not an array. In C, arrays are never passed as function arguments. Only pointers are passed. The syntax is deceptive and the creators of C have been/are sorry about things like this, but that's all history now. You can't change it.
3. In all C expressions (not to be confused with declarations and definitions), except about one, arrays behave as pointers to their first element. The exception is the `sizeof` operator. `sizeof(array)` will return you the true array size in `chars`. But the moment you do `sizeof(array+0)`, you have converted `array` to an expression of pointer type pointing to `array[0]` and in this case `sizeof` will return you the size of the pointer.
4. You cannot assign arrays. You can initialize them when you define them, you can copy them, but not assign with `=` after they have been defined.
5. There are no strings in C in the form of a fundamental type. There are only `chars`, arrays of `chars` and pointers to `chars` and pointers to arrays of `chars` and we often refer to all of them as strings, but they really aren't. The thing that you see as a string, e.g. `"I am a string. Or maybe I'm not."` is called a string literal and somewhere there is an array of `chars` associated with it. I say somewhere, because the string literal behaves differently in different contexts. In all C expressions (not to be confused with declarations/definitions), except about one, string literals behave as a pointer to the first `char` of an array containing the literal's text. The exception is, again, `sizeof`. It will return you the size of the underlying array of `chars` in something like `sizeof("ABC")`. Again, just like with arrays, the moment you write `sizeof("ABC"+0)`, you have converted `"ABC"` to a pointer to `char` and `sizeof` will return you the size of the pointer.
6. You must not attempt to modify the `char` arrays created by string literals: `"ABC"[0] = 'Z';` is undefined behavior. And so is `char* p = "ABC"; p[0] = 'Z';` or the equivalent `char* p = "ABC"; *p = 'Z';`.
7. You may use string literals to initialize arrays of `chars` or pointers to `chars` (you can also assign string literals to pointers, but not to arrays, arrays aren't assignable, as pointed out earlier). What happens depends on what you're initializing. In `char a[] = "Hello";` or in `char a[] = { "Hello!" };` you create an array of `chars` and you set its contents to be the text in the string literal. And you can modify that array afterwards if you need to. In `char* p = "World!";` you create a `char` array containing the text of the literal string and you create a pointer to a `char` pointing to the first `char` of that array. In this case you cannot alter the array as I pointed out earlier.
8. Two or more adjacent string literals delimited by space merge into one: `"Hello" " World!"` is the same as `"Hello World!"`.
9. There's also pointer arithmetic, but it's easy.

This is about it. Master declarations, master arrays in expressions and function parameters, watch your string literals.

Answer (score 0):

While re-inventing the wheel is not always desired. I tend to think that by doing so you get a greater understanding for how things work. Though, not sure what type of time-frame you're working in. Otherwise, as mentioned in another answer Better String Library is a very good one.