# How do strings and char arrays work in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string, c-strings

No guides I've seen seem to explain this very well.

I mean, you can allocate memory for a `char*`, or write `char[25]` instead? What's the difference? And then there are literals, which can't be manipulated? What if you want to assign a fixed string to a variable? Like, `stringVariable = "thisIsALiteral"`, then how do you manipulate it afterwards?

Can someone set the record straight here? And in the last case, with the literal, how do you take care of null-termination? I find this very confusing.

---

EDIT: The real problem seems to be that as I understand it, you have to juggle these different constructs in order to accomplish even simple things. For instance, only `char *` can be passed as an argument or return value, but only `char[]` can be assigned a literal and modified. I feel like it's obvious that we frequently/always needs to be able to do both, and that's where my pitfall is.

Comment: String literals are null terminated **by default** and are not modifiable. So, you cannot manipulate them.

Comment: String literals can be manipulated (used); they simply can't be modified.  This is actually an enormous question.

Comment: I kind of tried to answer this when [answering your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12719216/968261). Should I move that answer here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What is the difference between an allocated `char*` and `char[25]`?

The lifetime of a `malloc`-ed string is not limited by the scope of its declaration. In plain language, you can return `malloc`-ed string from a function; you cannot do the same with `char[25]` allocated in the *automatic storage*, because its memory will be reclaimed upon return from the function.

> Can literals be manipulated?

String literals cannot be manipulated in place, because they are allocated in read-only storage. You need to copy them into a modifiable space, such as static, automatic, or dynamic one, in order to manipulate them. This cannot be done:

```
char *str = "hello";
str[0] = 'H'; // <<== WRONG! This is undefined behavior.
```

This will work:

```
char str[] = "hello";
str[0] = 'H'; // <<=== This is OK
```

This works too:

```
char *str = malloc(6);
strcpy(str, "hello");
str[0] = 'H'; // <<=== This is OK too
```

> How do you take care of null termination of string literals?

C compiler takes care of null termination for you: all string literals have an extra character at the end, filled with `\0`.

Comment: There is useful information here, definitely, but many things are still confusing. What if you want the modifiability of `char[]` but also the freedom of function passing afforded by `char*`? Is there no middle ground?

Comment: @Aerovistae `malloc`-ed `char*` are modifiable as well, or you can use `strdup` to make a modifiable string that you can return from a function.

Comment: @Aerovistae: In C and C++ an array implicitly converts into a pointer. So if you have `char a[25]` and wish to pass it into a function `void f(const char *p)` you may call it as `f(a)` and it will just work.

Comment: @Aerovistae i have explained the middle ground in my answer with code sample. You need a conceptual clarification. It is NOT like 'create with char * if you want to pass to a function, and create with char [] if you want to modify it'

Comment: The first part of this answer is very misleading.

Comment: @GregA.Woods Could you perhaps be more specific? Feel free to offer an edit to make it more clear.

Comment: @epsalon's answer is more complete and I think far more helpful to a beginning user, especially if it were updated with additional information about global variables, such as I offer in my comment.  (although it should also be mentioned that having writable string literals is now a valid recognized common extension in C99)

Comment: @GregA.Woods That would be a valid reason to upvote his answer (and I assume you did that). Yet it most definitely has absolutely nothing to do with my answer. Is there anything factually wrong with my answer? Can you offer a specific way to improve the wordings? What specifically is misleading about the first part of my answer? Could you suggest a way in which it could be misunderstood?

Comment: like I said, the first part of your answer is very misleading, and the original poster apparently agreed.  The mention of `malloc()` there is out of place and irrelevant.  The discussion about return values is wrong for the case where the array is a global array (something entirely possible given the wording in the question).  Like I said, read @epsalon's answer for a more complete understanding of the differences between pointers and arrays, and read my comment on that answer too.  @fayyazkl's answer in place of your first section would improve your answer, but it's not complete yet either.

Comment: @GregA.Woods The OP asked about the second part of my answer, got a 2-line reply, which evidently cleared things out to his satisfaction. I clarified my answer to address the global vs. automatic difference.

Comment: What is a fifference between `char *str = "hello"` and `char str[] = "hello"`?

Answer (score 8):

Your question refers to three different constructs in C: char arrays, char pointers allocated on the heap, and string literals. These are all different is subtle ways.

- Char arrays, which you get by declaring `char foo[25]` inside a function, that memory is allocated on the stack, it exists only within the scope you declared it, but exactly 25 bytes have been allocated for you. You may store whatever you want in those bytes, but if you want a string, don't forget to use the last byte to null-terminate it.
- Character pointers defined with `char *bar` only hold a pointer to some unallocated memory. To make use of them you need to point them to something, either an array as before (`bar = foo`) or allocate space `bar = malloc(sizeof(char) * 25);`. If you do the latter, you should eventually free the space.
- String literals behave differently depending on how you use them. If you use them to initialize a char array `char s[] = "String";` then you're simply declaring an array large enough to exactly hold that string (and the null terminator) and putting that string there. It's the same as declaring a char array and then filling it up.

  On the other hand, if you assign a string literal to a `char *` then the pointer is pointing to memory you are not supposed to modify. Attempting to modify it may or may not crash, and leads to undefined behavior, which means you shouldn't do it.

Comment: and of course you can also define a global or static char array (i.e. one defined outside any function, and which has either a global symbol, or one private to a single source file).  In that case the memory for it is allocated by the compiler in either the "data" or the "bss" segment (`char s[] = "string";` would go in the former, and `char foo[25];` would go in the latter).

Answer (score 5):

Since other aspects are answered already, i would only add to the question "**what if you want the flexibility of function passing using char * but modifiability of char []**"

You can allocate an array and pass the same array to a function as char *. This is called *pass by reference* and internally only passes the *address* of actual array (precisely address of first element) instead of copying the whole. The other effect is that any change made inside the function *modifies the original array.*

```
void fun(char *a) {
   a[0] = 'y'; // changes hello to yello
}

main() {
   char arr[6] = "hello"; // Note that its not char * arr
   fun(arr); // arr now contains yello
}
```

The same could have been done for an array allocated with malloc

```
char * arr = malloc(6);
strcpy(arr, "hello");

fun(arr); // note that fun remains same.
```

Latter you can free the malloc memory

```
free(arr);
```

char * a, is just a pointer that can store address, which might be of a single variable or might be the first element of an array. Be ware, we have to *assign* to this pointer before actually using it.

Contrary to that char arr[SIZE] creates an array on the stack i.e. it also allocates SIZE bytes. So you can directly access arr[3] (assuming 3 is less than SIZE) without any issues.

Now *it makes sense to **allow assigning any address to a, but not allowing this for arr**, since there is no other way except using arr to access its memory.*

Comment: +100 for the last paragraph if possible. That had been confusing me for awhile.