# Setting CHAR16* to a #define string?

Tags: c++, c, variable-assignment

I'm a little confused on the proper way to do this. I have a `#DEFINE` that contains a string, and I have a `CHAR16*` that I want to set to that string. How would I properly do this? I've tried:

```
#DEFINE MYSTRING "HELLO"

CHAR16* THISONE;

THISONE = MYSTRING;
```

Why won't this work? I want to be able to print out the string in `THISONE`. I get a compiler warning regarding incompatible types. I'm sure I'm missing something small?

Comment: C or C++?  They're not the same.

Comment: You'll probably need something like L"HELLO" or u16"HELLO" because "HELLO" is a narrow string literal and most probably not compatible to CHAR16*.

Comment: What is `CHAR16`? No such type is defined by the C or C++ standard. And `#DEFINE` is a syntax error; it's `#define`.

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't put my real code for NDA issues. I'm working with EDK2's framework, I should have mentioned. This is C.

Comment: Oh EFI, sometimes I really don't miss you....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're defining a narrow string literal `"HELLO"`, but trying to use a `CHAR16` pointer to point to it.  That's not a compatible assignment.  As `clang` says:

```
example.cpp:9:13: error: assigning to 'wchar_t *' from incompatible type
      'const char [6]'
    THISONE = MYSTRING;
            ^ ~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

(I changed the type from `CHAR16 *` to `wchar_t *` since I'm not on windows - the semantics are the same).

To fix it, you need to add an `L` in front of the string constant:

```
#define MYSTRING L"HELLO"
```

And then it will compile.  In C, you're done.  In C++, however, you will probably still get a warning:

```
example.cpp:9:15: warning: conversion from string literal to 'wchar_t *' is
      deprecated [-Wdeprecated-writable-strings]
    THISONE = MYSTRING;
              ^
example.cpp:3:18: note: expanded from macro 'MYSTRING'
#define MYSTRING L"HELLO"
                 ^
1 warning generated.
```

Change the definition to:

```
const wchar_t *THISONE;
```

To fix that warning.  I guess in your case that would be:

```
const CHAR16 *THISONE;
```

Editorial note - in the future, please show your real code.  `#DEFINE` (with the capital letters) isn't valid C or C++.

Comment: On which platform/compiler is a *narrow* string literal of the type *array of n const CHAR16*? I'm confused.

Comment: None, probably.  Did I say it was?

Comment: No, but I guess that might be another problem in the example of the OP - or isn't it?

Comment: Yeah - you're probably right.  I had to test with `char *` here because I don't have windows.  Let me try something out...

Comment: @DyP - fixed up, thanks.  My original test didn't make sense.  I think I've explained everything now.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like:

```
// Update: As carl points out, there is more to this for wide chars
const CHAR16* THISONE = MYSTRING;
```

You can explore more about [c-strings here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson9.html) and also from [within this very site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718929/how-do-strings-and-char-arrays-work-in-c).

Comment: This is a problem, but not one that causes an error, probably.

Comment: Yes sir, just occured to me that a wide char in c++ should also be more specific: L"mystring", just as ST3 points out

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to assign it as a global variable. In this case you need:

```
#define MYSTRING "HELLO"
CHAR* THISONE = MYSTRING;
```

or

```
#define MYSTRING L"HELLO"
CHAR16* THISONE = MYSTRING;
```

If assignment is in function (main() or other) you can make assignment not at the same place as variable creation.

Actually, I'm not sure if there is such a type "CHAR16"