# What happens to strings under the hood in C?

Tags: c, arrays, string

Transitioning myself from Python to C for an algorithms course, it has been really difficult for me to understand how common strings work in this new hell.

**From what I've understood:**

- In C, there are no strings per se, but rather an array of characters.
- Variable names of arrays point to the address of the first element in an array (which in memory is lined up), thus lacking the need to point out to every single character.

**What confuses me is the following:**

```
char greeting[] = "Hello world";
printf("%s", greeting);
```

1) How come there is no need to pass an array to greeting[ ] like {"H", "e", "l", "l", "o"} etc but a single string is enough?

2) Why does printf print out the whole message, when it's in actuality a  simple array? Does using the string format in prinf go through a for loop, printing out each element without a new-line?

```
char *greeting = "Hello world";
printf("%s", greeting);
```

3) What? Let me get guess this... C takes the inserted string, gets its length, creates an array of characters and then does the point (2) magic? What kind of shenigans does the pointer variable do? Something something a[ ] == &a AND a[0] == *a???

```
char *moreGreetings[] = {"Hello", "Greetings", "Good morning"};
printf("%s", moreGreetings[0]); // Returns "Hello"
```

4) I just can't anymore... why does calling moreGreetings[0] call out the whole array of characters "Hello"???

Unless there is a bunch of shenigans going on under the hood, I have no idea how any of this makes sense. Could someone PLEASE explain what is going on?

Comment: Each `char[]` "String" is terminated by a `'\0'`.

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do strings and char arrays work in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12718929/how-do-strings-and-char-arrays-work-in-c)

Comment: A classic blog post on C strings, from one of the founders of Stack Overflow: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/

Comment: Maybe there are valid reasons to close this question, but off-topic is utter nonsense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Computers are aliens. They think nothing like we do. ***Computers don't know what strings are.***

Programming languages are human-to-alien translators. Python is like reading an idiomatically translated book. C is like reading a literal translation, and even then it does a lot of work.

> 1) How come there is no need to pass an array to greeting[ ] like {"H", "e", "l", "l", "o"} etc but a single string is enough?

The compiler takes care of it for you. Also you're missing the null byte at the end. And those aren't characters.

C is the ultimate DIY language. Coming from Python it can be ***very*** disorienting. C gives you the bare minimum (yes, I see you Assembly programmers waving your arms in the back, don't complicate things). It does this A) to be very fast and B) to let you build anything. Unfortunately it doesn't always do this in the most obvious way. If you don't understand what's going on under the hood in C, the details of how computer memory works, you're in trouble.

For example, be careful of `"` vs `'`. `'H'` is the single character H, really the short (ie. 1 byte) integer 72 (the exact number depends on your locale). `"H"` is a two character array, `{'H', '\0'}` which is really `{72, 0}`.

The key thing to understand about strings in C, and all arrays, is they're just a hunk of memory split into 1 byte chunks. That's ***it***. They don't even store their own length, you have to either store that somewhere else (like in a struct) or terminate the list with something.

C strings are a hunk of memory split into 1 byte chunks terminated by a null byte (ie. 0). That's it. These are *conceptually* equivalent.

```
const char *string = "Hello";
char string[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
```

Both will contain the same bytes, they differ in how they're stored.

> 2) Why does printf print out the whole message, when it's in actuality a simple array? Does using the string format in prinf go through a for loop, printing out each element without a new-line?

`printf` is kinda like Python's `str`. You tell it how to convert the thing into characters, and it'll convert the thing. `%s` says it's a character array terminated by a null byte. `%d` says it's an integer. `%f` says a floating point number. All of these things are represented differently in memory and need different conversions to characters.

How `printf` actually works is an implementation detail, but it's a good exercise to implement it yourself. And you can do it with a for loop writing out one byte at a time and stopping at the null byte.

```
for( const char *pos = string; pos[0] != '\0'; pos++ ) {
    putchar(pos[0]);
}
```

Note that rather than indexing through the array, I'm moving forward where the start of the array is. `string` is nothing more but a pointer to the start of the array. By copying it to `pos` I can change that pointer without affecting `string`. This avoids having to allocate an extra integer for the index, and it avoids having to do the extra math of an array lookup. `pos[0]` just reads 1 byte after `pos`.

And yes, if you forget that null byte it'll just keep on going reading the memory past the end of the string until it happens to see a 0 or the operating system smacks it for going out of the bounds of the process.

> 3) What? Let me get guess this... C takes the inserted string, gets its length, creates an array of characters and then does the point (2) magic? What kind of shenigans does the pointer variable do? Something something a[ ] == &a AND a[0] == *a???

No, C strings don't store the length. To get the length they'd have to iterate through the whole string, and then iterate through the whole string again to print it. Instead they print to the null byte.

> 4) I just can't anymore... why does calling moreGreetings[0] call out the whole array of characters "Hello"???

Because `moreGreetings` is an array of pointers to more character arrays. `char *moreGreetings[]` is *roughly* equivalent to `char **moreGreetings`. It's a pointer to a pointer to characters.

It's an array of strings and you asked for the first one, so you get a string out.

---

Keep in mind, ***Python is written in C*** (yeah, there's other implementations now). C is the bottom of the stack (almost). Python, and every other program, eventually has to deal with these same "shenanigans" C does, but really its dealing with the reality of how computers work.

Often they don't use C strings because they're so ungainly and error prone, they make up their own, but they're still filling fixed sized hunks of memory with numbers and calling them "strings".

---

The best advice I can give you is to turn on compiler warnings. All of them! C compiler warnings can shine a light on many simple mistakes, but they're off by default. The typical way you turn them on is with `-Wall`, but that's not all warnings. There's lots and lots of extras. This is the formula I use in my Makefile (have a Makefile).

```
CFLAGS  += -Wall -Wshadow -Wwrite-strings -Wextra -Wconversion -std=c99 -pedantic $(OPTIMIZE)
```

That turns on "all" warnings, and "extra" warnings, and some additional specific warnings I've found useful. It says I'm using the ISO C standard from 1999 (more on that in a moment) and I want the compiler to be pedantic about following the standard so my code is portable between compilers and environments. I do a lot of Open Source work, but it's good when you're started so you don't get addicted to non-standard compiler extensions.

About the standard. C is quite old and was only standardized in 1990. Many, many people learned to code with non-standard C, and you see that in a lot of C teaching material. Even though there's a 2011 standard, many C programmers write and teach to C90 or even earlier. Even C99 is considered "new" by many. Visual Studio is particularly bad at standards compliance, but they're finally catching up in the latest versions.

Comment: `char *string = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'}` is **not** equivalent to `char *string = "Hello"`. The former is interpreted as `char *string = 'H'` and crashes when the string is accessed at run-time. The fact that the accepted answer by a reputable contributor contains this sort of error ironically reinforces the OP's point of C strings being a "hell".

Comment: @user4815162342 Yeah, should have run that through a compiler, but let's not get overly dramatic. I've only been doing C seriously for a couple years. There's always another exception to learn. And don't forget when pointing out a mistake in C to *post the correct thing*. I honestly can't explain why one uses `char *string` and the other uses `char string[]`. Can you?

Comment: `char *string="Hello";` is very different than `char string[] = "Hello"`.  The former creates a local variable named string that contains the address of an object that contains the characters in the string.  The latter creates a local variable named string which contains the characters.  When the function returns, those characters are no longer available.  A pointer is *not* an array.

Comment: Everyone can make a mistake, no worries. The remark was meant in a affirmative way - C arrays, pointers and strings *are* hard to explain. As for pointing out the correct thing, that is the one that doesn't crash, as explained in some detail by William.

Answer (score 4):

> 1) How come there is no need to pass an array to greeting[ ] like {"H", "e", "l", "l", "o"} etc but a single string is enough?

Because the C syntax allows for "string" literals, which are a shorthand way of representing a C-style string.

Incidentally, `{"H", "e", "l", "l", "o"}` is an array of strings, not an array of `char`s. An array of characters would look like this: `{'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o'}`, but `"Hello"` actually represents the array `{ 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' }` (strings work by having a string termination character `\0` at the end).

> 2) Why does printf print out the whole message, when it's in actuality a simple array? Does using the string format in prinf go through a for loop, printing out each element without a new-line?

The `%s` token tells `printf` that you want it to treat the value as a "string", so it handles it as one, printing characters one by one until it encounters the string termination character `\0`, which is automatically at the end of any "string" you create using the string literal syntax.

> 3) What? Let me get guess this... C takes the inserted string, gets its length, creates an array of characters and then does the point (2) magic? What kind of shenigans does the pointer variable do? Something something a[ ] == &a AND a[0] == *a???

I have no idea what this question means.

> 4) I just can't anymore... why does calling moreGreetings[0] call out the whole array of characters "Hello"???

`moreGreetings` is an array of strings (or an array of pointers to arrays of `chars`, if you like). So `moreGreetings[0]` is the first element in that array, which is the "string" `"Hello"`. If you pass that into `printf` and use `%s` to tell it to treat the value as a string, then it will.

Comment: W.r.t. (4), `moreGreetings` is better described as an array of *pointers* to (the first elements of) arrays than as an array of arrays.  Although the distinction may presently seem arcane to the OP, it is exactly the kind of detail that will ultimately help him get this all straight.  Better to not set him up for confusion when he sees an actual array of arrays (i.e. a 2D array).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thank you. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

> How come there is no need to pass an array to greeting[ ] like {"H", "e", "l", "l", "o"} etc but a single string is enough?

It is indeed possible to assign `"Hello"` as an array.

```
char greetings[] = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};
```

But this assignment is very hard to write so `char greetings[] = "Hello"` will be a shortcut. But the two assignments are the same.

> Why does printf print out the whole message?

`printf` has different behaviors depending on the format argument it receives. When you ask printf to print a value in string format `%s`, it takes a pointer to a character and prints its value as well as its subsequent characters one by one until it reaches the null terminator `\0`.

> Why does calling moreGreetings[0] call out the whole array of characters "Hello"?

A pointer to the array is a pointer to the first element of that array. So in both `printf("%s", greetings[0]);` and `printf("%s", greetings);` you are passing a pointer to the same memory location, which produces the same output.

Answer (score 0):

1. It's a language feature - you can initialize an array of chars using a string literal, and it will do what you meant, i.e. `char greeting[] = "foo"` will be interpreted as `char greeting[] = {'f', 'o', 'o', '\0'}`. This comes without a price because otherwise `char greeting[] = "foo"` would be a compile-time error.
2. Google C array decay. In short, passing an array where a pointer is expected will behave as if the pointer to the first element of the array was passed. This is useful in many contexts, especially with strings.
3. See #2.
4. Because you declared an array of pointers to `char` (strings), and are passing the first of those pointers to `printf`. It is equivalent to writing `printf("%s", "Hello")`.

Answer (score 0):

1) How come there is no need to pass an array to greeting[ ] like {"H", "e", "l", "l", "o"} etc but a single string is enough?

When you pass an array or a string (it turns out that they are both the same thing), you are giving the memory address of the first element in the array.  Because array elements are stored in memory, one after another, all that is needed to access the next element in the array (or character in string) is to increment the memory address that was passed.

2) Why does printf print out the whole message, when it's in actuality a simple array? Does using the string format in prinf go through a for loop, printing out each element without a new-line?

Usually, all the system supports is a simple putchar() function call.  In order to use more convenient IO function, libraries were created.  The printf function probably uses a for loop to print each element in the string.

3) What? Let me get guess this... C takes the inserted string, gets its length, creates an array of characters and then does the point (2) magic? What kind of shenigans does the pointer variable do? Something something a[ ] == &a AND a[0] == *a???

The C compiler does count the length of the string.  I just want to clarify that this does not happen at runtime, it happens at compiletime.  During runtime, the string is referred to by its pointer.

The pointer variable is just an ordinary variable.  It just contains some memory address, somewhere.  In order for the compiler to know how to treat the pointer, the pointer is given a type, i.e. int*, char*.

Note:  There is such a thing as a void* without a referencing type.

When the program wants to access a memory location directly next to that pointed by some pointer, let's call it int*p, it just increments the value of p by p++ or p + 1.

Comment: I forgot to mention something extremely important to this discussion.  Strings in C are NULL terminated.  This means that your array greetings[] = "hello";  will look like this: greetings = {'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0'};  where '\0' is the null character.  You could also just put the NULL instead of '\0'.

Comment: You can edit your answer to amend it in any way you like.

Comment: "Usually, all the system supports is a simple putchar() function call." That seems like hell to anyone who wants fast I/O. Linux has the `write` system call, which writes an arbitrary number of bytes to a certain file. For stuff like printing characters on the screen, vectorization can speed up things significantly and a "simple putchar()" doesn't make this possible. BTW, you might benefit from using more mark-up like ">>" for citations or backticks for inline code.

Comment: You're completely right!  I did oversimplify my answer.